# Can I already install TeX Live 2019 using install-tl?

Tags: texlive, debian

I'm using Debian testing and it has packages (containing e.g. the *latex* executable) from TeX Live 2019.

Can I already use *install-tl* with some `-repository ...` flag to install the same packages to some non-Debian system? What is the flag value?

Comment: I very much doubt it is: pre-testing hasn't even started!

Comment: TeXLive 2019... with Debian? Debian tends to have rather outdated packages for TL. Now Debian is ahead? ;-)

Comment: You can use LuaTeX from TeX Live 2019 for which I host an unofficial repository for x86_64 Linux: https://github.com/hmenke/texlive-luatex-dev

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OP is on testing which is very different from stable in terms of software versions.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Well, I misunderstood Debian testing apparently

Comment: @pts sorry to highjack this question, but I tried to write you about magyar.ldf which is not compatible with the next latex but the email bounced. Could you tell me how to contact you at best?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: By now you should have received an e-mail to reply to. If it bounces, let me know.

Comment: @pts I sent an answer some minutes ago. It didn't bounced yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX Live 2019 is not yet released, in fact it hasn't even entered the pretest phase yet.  What you are observing is a “bug” in Debian, that the binaries report the wrong version string<sup>1</sup>.  The version shipped with Debian is actually the same as the one in TeX Live 2018.  You can check using

```
$ luatex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
**\relax

*\directlua{print(status.development_id)}
6686
```

And here for comparison from vanilla TeX Live 2018, installed from https://tug.org/texlive/

```
$ luatex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
**\relax

*\directlua{print(status.development_id)}
6686
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not really a bug because it does not affect the functionality in any way.  Calling it a “glitch” or “inaccuracy” might be more appropriate.  Also keep in mind that you are using Debian *testing*.

Comment: Thank you for the details! I'm aware that I'm using Debian testing, it's the 4th word in my question.

Comment: @pts I wanted to emphasize that it's called *testing* for a reason.

Answer (score 7):

Debian does not ship the binaries that are shipped in TUG TeX Live 2018, but the binaries in Debian are built from a snapshot of the development sources to get lots of bugfixes and some improvements. I have updated the binaries as far as possible (skipping the incompatible luatex update). Thus, the binaries in Debian correctly refer to themselves as built from the 2019/dev development branch, but are **not** those that will go into TeX Live 2019 - for this the `/dev` part would disappear.